# Migrate partial data from one database to other database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How can we move partial data (top 50 rows) of all tables in SQL Server?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? What functions/syntax have you looked at? If you haven't, here's a few hints: `TOP`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the export task in sql server management studio.